# Validación PDO, si el documento no existe, muestre el valor 0

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo la siguiente consulta PDO para mostrar un saldo traído de la BD:

**Vista**

```
<?php
     $item = "documento";
     $valor = $documento;
     $saldo = ControladorCuadros::ctrMostrarSaldo($item, $valor);
              foreach ($saldo as $key => $value) {
                    $saldo = $value["saldo"];
              }
?>
```

**Controlador**

```
static public function ctrMostrarSaldo($item, $valor){
        $tabla = "datos";
        $respuesta = ModeloCuadros::mdlMostrarSaldo($tabla, $item, $valor);
        return $respuesta;
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
static public function mdlMostrarSaldo($tabla, $item, $valor){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        $stmt -> close();
        $stmt = null;
    }
```

Hasta ahí, todo bien... Me muestra el saldo cuando el documento existe en la tabla pero si no existe, muestra este error:
**Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs...\vista.php.**

Cómo puedo validar si el documento no existe que me muestre el valor en cero?

Comment: Prueba esto: `$data=$stmt -> fetchAll(); return ( $data ) ? $data : 0;` Por cierto, si haces `$stmt -> close();` no necesitas usar también `$stmt = null;`, y ponlo antes del `return`. Todo lo que hay después de un `return` no se ejecuta en una función. `return`es como decir al código: *no pases de aquí, retorna a la línea que e llamó.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que dice el [Manual de PHP sobre `fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> #### Valores devueltos
>
> `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` devuelve un array que contiene tadas las
>   filas restantes del conjunto de resultados. El array representa cada
>   fila como un array con valores de las columnas, o como un objeto con
>   propiedades correspondientes a cada nombre de columna. **Es devuelto
>   un array vacío si hay cero resultados que obtener, o FALSE en caso de
>   fallo**.

Puedes usar un operador ternario que evalúe el resultado de `fetchAll`, devolviendo dicho resultado o `0`.

```
static public function mdlMostrarSaldo($tabla, $item, $valor){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();
        /*Almacenamos el resultado en $data*/
        $data=$stmt -> fetchAll();
        /*Esto debe ir antes del return. Ya tenemos los datos, podemos cerrarlo*/
        $stmt = NULL; //Si quieres, para tranquilizar la conciencia

        /*
           *Aquí se evalúa $data:
           * - si no es FALSE o NULL devuelve $data
           * - si es FALSE o NULL devuelve 0
        */
        return ( $data ) ? $data : 0;
    }
```

---

#### Corrigiendo el error de lógica al recibir los datos

Dado que `mdlMostrarSaldo` retornará `0` en caso de no haber resultados, debes adaptar el código donde lees el resultado de la llamada a esa función. Cuando retorne `0` no puedes usar un `foreach` para leer los datos, porque `0` no es un array. Entonces tienes que hacer algo así:

```
 $saldo = ControladorCuadros::ctrMostrarSaldo($item, $valor);
 if ($saldo!=0) {
          foreach ($saldo as $key => $value) {
                $saldo = $value["saldo"];
          }
  }
```

> **ADVERTENCIA SOBRE UN ERROR DE LÓGICA:** En tu código se aprecia un problema de lógica. En esta línea dentro del `foreach`: **`$saldo=$value["saldo"];`** se van a sobre-escribir las posibles filas que
>   retorne `fetchAll`, y el valor de `$saldo` se quedará únicamente con
>   el último registro. Esto no tiene ningún sentido. No sé que uso le das
>   a esos datos luego, pero lo correcto sería crear una variable de
>   retorno para devolverla a la vista o donde sea. Dentro del `foreach`, se va concatenando cada fila (con `.=`) a esa variable  de retorno. Algo así:
>
> ```
>  $saldo = ControladorCuadros::ctrMostrarSaldo($item, $valor);
>  $output="No se encontraron registros";
>
>  if ($saldo!=0) {
>           $output="";
>           foreach ($saldo as $key => $value) {
>                 $output .= $value["saldo"].PHP_EOL;
>           }
>   }
>   //retornar o imprimir $output
> ```
>
> Otra cosa de la que debes asegurarte es que los datos que retorna `fetchAll` tengan una clave llamado `saldo`. Para verificar puedes hacer un `var_dump($saldo)` antes del `foreach`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Probé con tu sugerencia y pasa lo siguiente: con `close();` antes de `return` como lo sugieres, no muestra valores pero si este error desde la primera fila: _Fatal error ":  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::close() in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\archivo.modelo.php:20"_ y si pongo primero el `return` y luego el  `close();` muestra todos los valores y el 0 en la última fila, pero también este warning en la ultima fila: _Warning ":  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\archivo.php:42"_. Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET es cierto el mensaje de error con respecto a `close`, de hecho [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php) no tiene un método `close`. De todos modos, no tienes que preocuparte por cerrarlo, cuando el script que lo usa no está más activo se cerrará solo, de hecho [los ejemplos del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) no lo usan. Si te remuerde la conciencia, puedes hacer algo como `$stmt=NULL;` Lo que sí confirma la situación que comentas es lo que te dije en la respuesta: **el código no estaba pasando por esa línea**.

Comment: En cuanto a la advertencia *Warning ": Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*, no tiene nada que ver con este código, **no hay ningún `foreach` aquí**. Esa advertencia tiene que ver seguramente con otra parte de tu código, quizá donde manejas la respuesta que recibes al invocar a `mdlMostrarSaldo`.

Comment: Es correcto. El warning hace referencia a la vista, cuyo código es el que puse arriba, en la pregunta. Tendrías la gentileza de mirarlo para ver si me puedes dar alguna sugerencia respecto a ese fragmento?. Perdón si abuso, pero apenas estoy conociendo el patrón MVC.

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET Dado que `mdlMostrarSaldo` retornará `0` en caso de no haber resultados, debes adaptar el código donde lees el resultado de la llamada a esa función. Además hay un error de lógica en tu código, revisa mi respuesta al final donde lo he intentando explicar con claridad.

Comment: Mil gracias por la aclaración. Teniendo en cuenta tus sugerencias, lo resolví validando si la respuesta es un array o un objeto antes del ciclo: `if (is_array($saldo) || is_object($saldo)) { foreach... }`. De nuevo gracias por la explicación, por la claridad y sobre todo por la paciencia.